# Вычисление площади треугольника по координатам вершин

Tags: python, алгоритм, математика

Заданы координаты трех точек в пространстве (все величины по модулю не превышают 10^9 и являются целыми числами). Необходимо вычислить площадь образованного ими треугольника. При этом нужно постараться максимально точно произвести все вычисления (примерно до 6 знаков после запятой). Первое приходящее на ум решение: вычислить длину всех сторон по формуле длины вектора в пространстве, затем посчитать площадь по формуле Герона. Моя реализация выглядит следующим образом:

```
import math
import decimal

x1, y1, z1 = map(float, input().split())
x2, y2, z2 = map(float, input().split())
x3, y3, z3 = map(float, input().split())

len_1 = decimal.Decimal(math.sqrt((x1 - x2) ** 2 + (y1 - y2) ** 2 + (z1 - z2) ** 2))
len_2 = decimal.Decimal(math.sqrt((x2 - x3) ** 2 + (y2 - y3) ** 2 + (z2 - z3) ** 2))
len_3 = decimal.Decimal(math.sqrt((x1 - x3) ** 2 + (y1 - y3) ** 2 + (z1 - z3) ** 2))

p = decimal.Decimal((len_1 + len_2 + len_3) / 2)

square = decimal.Decimal(math.sqrt(p * (p - len_1) * (p - len_2) * (p - len_3)))
print(square)
```

Для обеспечения максимального уровня точности использую decimal.Decimal (хотя, стандартного float, скорее всего, хватило бы для обеспечения необходимой точности). При сдаче задачи на тестировщик решение проходит только 14 из 20 тестов. С чем это может быть связано? Может быть такое, что точность теряется при многочисленном взятии корней или что-то в этом роде?
Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: `S = ½|AB x AC|`

Comment: @АндрейNOP третик скуп - то есть пополам

Comment: @Igor, плюс константа

Answer (score 2):

### Воспользуйтесь формулой ориентированной площади.

У вас есть три точки A, B, C, вычислите два вектора AB и AC (разность координат точек: AB = B - A, AC = C - A), затем возьмите их координаты (обозначим их x1, y1, x2, y2), запишите их в виде матрицы 2 на 2 и посчитайте её детерминант:

```
D = x1 y2 - x2 y1
```

Искомая площадь равна половине модуля детерминанта:

```
S = |D| = |x1 y2 - x2 y1|/2
```

Статья по теме: [ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Псевдоскалярное_произведение](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Comment: Статья по теме: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Псевдоскалярное_произведение

Comment: Спасибо, добавлю ссылку в ответ.

Comment: В задаче точка задана на плоскости, т.е. имеет три координаты.

Comment: Точно, не заметил сразу. Тогда векторное произведение, лучше ничего не придумать. Ну или обобщить формулу для площади через определитель 3 на 3 (получили объём пирамиды), и поделить на расстояние до плоскости (это просто свободный член уравнения плоскости при правильной нормировке).

Answer (score 1):

> Может быть такое, что точность теряется

Может. Используйте векторное произведение.

Answer (score 0):

Единственное,как мне кажется,что сильно влияет на погрешность,так это sqrt.
Там же есть фишка с float,что он может хранить e^380,но на самом деле промежуточная часть может искажаться.
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Тоже 14 из 20,чертов НТИ :)

UPD:
Если решать через векторное произведение,то тоже 14 из 20

Comment: Тогда вообще непонятно, в чем может быть дело

Comment: Сегодня думал пофиксить точность через формулу Герона,но тут твою статью увидел)

Comment: Через векторное произведение работает, проходит все тесты.